# ServiceStack SwaggerUI: Models disappear when SwaggerUI is set to a single resource

Tags: c#, javascript, servicestack, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm not sure if this is a bug with the Swagger JavaScript or the generated Swagger JSON, but it seems that when I point SwaggerUI at a single resource (i.e. /resource/MyResource  vs. /resources), the models don't seem to be parsed correctly.    When I view all the resources in one shot via the "/resources" url, the Models appear correctly as both response classes and input (body type) parameters.  When I switch the url to a single resource, all the models disappear.   The names and descriptions of input parameters remain, as well as the overall "method signature."   This doesn't seem to happen with the Swagger Petstore demo (though granted, it is using a newer version of Swagger).   Is there anything I should be doing in terms of the Swagger related API attributes that would help with this?

### EDIT

As a workaround, I'm using the latest SwaggerUI (which is based on the Swagger 1.2 spec, but I'm not changing any of the ServiceStack.Api.Swagger code to support that) against my service.  I had to force SwaggerUI to request the resource(s) in JSON format by modifying swagger.js to add the "Accept: 'application/json'", but once I did that, it seems to work when pointing to a single resource.  So, this could just be a matter of updating the embedded SwaggerUI in ServiceStack.API.Swagger to the latest version.